# DataGridView binding to two tables

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datatable

I have two tables. Most of the data is coming from the first table but there is a second table which has a column which I want to present in my UI

Here is my SQL Query

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT u.CallerName, t.* FROM users u INNER JOIN tickets t ON u.id = t.user WHERE u.CallerName = 'tim.smith'";
```

I am using WinForms

Comment: How di I get data from the users table? My grid is bound to the tickets table via Designer

Comment: Is this for the winforms datagridview control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query result is [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t31h6yhs.aspx), then you can use [Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) function to merge two table.

```
DataTable table1 = GetTable1Data(...);
DataTable table2 = GetTable2Data(...);

table1.Merge(table2, true);
```

Or if your query result is [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), then you can use same approach as in DataTable case, using [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function:

```
List<YourClassType> list1 = GetList1Data(...);
List<YourClassType> list2 = GetList2Data(...);

list1.AddRange(list2, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing just fine.
When binding with the DataGridView you can use: 
`Eval("CallerName")`
to access the other column, but that column should work like all of the others.

Comment: Do i do this in the Designer?

Comment: I have never really used the designer, so I do not know. I generally work with the XML asp files.
If you were adding a list view you could say something like
`<asp:Label text='<%# Eval("CallerName") %>' runat="server" >`