# C# How to load data into DataGridView from multible tables [SQL Server]

Tags: c#, sql, database

How can I load data from 2 SQL Server tables into 1 datagridview? Like I have 2 tables:

```
Jobs:Job_ID, Client_ID
```

and

```
EmployeeJobs:Emp_ID, Job_ID, Hours_Spent, Job_Date
```

I want them to appear in one datagridview, what's the proper way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView binding to two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302272/datagridview-binding-to-two-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Bind datagridview to the following SQL select:

```
SELECT Jobs.Job_ID, Jobs.Client_ID, EmployeeJobs.Emp_ID, EmployeeJobs.Job_ID, EmployeeJobs.Hours_Spent, EmployeeJobs.Jobs_Date
FROM Jobs
INNER JOIN EmployeeJobs
ON Jobs.Job_ID=EmployeeJobs.Job_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL JOIN the tables, bind the result to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connetionString;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet changes;
        string Sql;
        Int32 i; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            Sql = "select * from Product";
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection);
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                connection.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                changes = ds.GetChanges();
                if (changes != null)
                {
                    adapter.Update(changes);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Changes Done");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another way to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            connection.Open();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Authors_table");
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "Authors_table";
        }
    }
}
```